# apt-get and aptitude seem to disagree -- do I really have broken packages?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, aptitude

If I do `aptitude search ~b` I get a list of 78 broken packages.  But 76 of them aren't even installed (they have a status of `pB`).  How can an uninstalled package be considered broken??

But if I do `apt-get -s install -f` it says there is nothing to do, so apparently `apt-get` doesn't think anything is broken.

And given that aptitude thinks a package is broken, how do I figure out *why* it thinks the package is broken?

Some output:

```
# aptitude search "~i ~b"
iB  foomatic-db-compressed-ppds                                    - OpenPrinting printer support - Compressed PPDs derived from the database
iB  xz-lzma                                                        - XZ-format compression utilities - compatibility commands
```

Those really are the only two.  But if I do just `~b` then I get a bunch of uninstalled broken (whatever that means) packages.  Here are the first few (of 76):

```
# aptitude search ~b
pB  bison                           - YACC-compatible parser generator
pB  compiz-fusion-plugins-extra     - transitional dummy package.
pB  compiz-fusion-plugins-main      - transitional dummy package.
pB  cpu-checker                     - tools to help evaluate certain CPU (or BIO
```

As for dpkg,

```
# dpkg-query -l xz-lzma
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                          Version                       Description
+++-=============================-=============================-==========================================================================
ii  xz-lzma                       5.1.1alpha+20110809-3         XZ-format compression utilities - compatibility commands
```

So what's going on?  And how do I fix it (if there's even anything actually broken)?

Comment: You shouldn't run `aptitude search` or `dpkg-query` as root. You should use sudo when needed but sudo is not needed to run either one of these commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is probably nothing really wrong.

Simple answer: `apt-get` and `aptitude` have different dependency resolvers ([how-do-i-fix-these-broken-dependencies](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60478/how-do-i-fix-these-broken-dependencies)).

To see if there is actually an issue you can run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall foomatic-db-compressed-ppds xz-lzma
```

Personally, I would advise against using `aptitude` as it can sometimes be dangerous.

`apt-get` is **much safer** and will not install with broken packages in place, however, `apt-get` is rarely, if ever, able to to fix an impossible situation because of broken packages. `aptitude` *does* have ability to *fix* broken packages but `aptitude` *also* has the ability to *create* a situation where broken packages exist.

A happy medium is `synaptic`. `synaptic` has more ability to fix broken packages than `apt-get` but does not have quite the ability of `aptitude` to create such a situation.

Sources: [how-do-i-fix-these-broken-dependencies](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60478/how-do-i-fix-these-broken-dependencies)

Comment: When I run those commands it works fine, so I guess it's not really broken, then.

But wasn't there a time when aptitude was considered better than apt-get?  When did it change back?

Comment: Better is just a matter of opinion. Aptitude is certainly more powerful but apt-get is safer.